# send text with question to bing chat via url and get the answer

Tags: php, chat, bing

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to send some text to the bing chat, ask him a custom request em get the answer all in PHP...

Would this be possible? I tried look for an FREE API but I did't find...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make HTTP requests to the Bing UI in code and read/parse the responses?  This is often called "site scraping" or "screen scraping".  Your PHP code can make an HTTP request (either directly or using a "headless browser" like Selenium, if the target page has a lot of client-side functionality) and parse the resulting responses to find the data you're looking for.  You are encouraged to start with some examples/tutorials on this and make an attempt.

Comment: The technique may be confused with scraping. Be if you read carefully, you will see that this is not the case. "send some text to the bing chat, ask him a custom request em get the answer all in PHP"

Comment: Bing chat doesn't yet have an API but Microsoft have suggested there may be one soon. So maybe just be patient. In the meantime perhaps try out similar AIs such as ChatGPT which does have an API. As this is cutting edge technology which is very expensive to develop and maintain, expecting to get full programmable access to it for free is pretty unrealistic really. You should expect to pay, if only a small amount depending how much you use it.